# Toggle button that changes DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to make a button that, when clicked, can change the text above it. But, I also want to make it where when you press it again, it will change it back. Here's the code that I've got so far, but the button isn't doing anything.

```html
<!doctype.html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Javascript</h1>
  <p id="display">Change my text!</p>
  <button onClick="writeMe()">Click me!</button>
</body>
<script>
  function writeMe() {
    if (document.getElementById("display") === "Change my text!") {
      document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Hello world!";
    } else if (document.getElementById("display") === "Hello world!") {
      document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Change my text!";
    }
  }
</script>

</html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: your if statement is missing .innerhtml if(document.getElementById("display").innerHTML === "Change my text!")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementById()` returns an **element**, it's never equal to *any* string.

Use a proper event handler, and check the elements `textContent` property instead, and then set that property if you just want to change the text.
If you wanted to add actual HTML, you'd use `innerHTML` instead.

```js
document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', writeMe)

function writeMe() {
  var display = document.getElementById("display");

  if ( display.textContent === "Change my text!" ) {
  
    display.textContent = "Hello world!";
    
  } else if ( display.textContent === "Hello world!" ) {
  
    display.textContent = "Change my text!";
    
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Javascript</h1>
<p id="display">Change my text!</p>
<button id="myButton">Click me!</button>
```

There's probably an even DRY'er way to write those `if` statements, but this is verbose, and should be easy to read.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Javascript</h1>
    <p id="display">Change my text!</p>
    <button onClick="writeMe()">Click me!</button>
</body>
<script>
    function writeMe() {
        if (document.getElementById("display").innerHTML === "Change my text!") {
            document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Hello world!";
        } else if (document.getElementById("display").innerHTML === "Hello world!") {
            document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Change my text!";
        }
    }
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting to mention `innerHTML` on if condition checking

```js
function writeMe() {
  if (document.getElementById("display").innerHTML === "Change my text!") {
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Hello world!";
  } else if (document.getElementById("display").innerHTML === "Hello world!") {
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Change my text!";
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="display">Change my text!</p>
<button onClick="writeMe()">Click me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add .innerHTML in your if statements

Answer (score 0):

Use .innerHtml to get the string as to get the text html we need to use innerHtml.

```
 function writeMe() {
        if (document.getElementById("display").innerHTML === "Change my text!") {
            document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Hello world!";
        }
        else if (document.getElementById("display").innerHTML === "Hello world!") {
            document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Change my text!";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just forgot the `.innerHTML` property of your element to read and compare.  Without that, you're just targeting the element itself, which won't be equal to any text string.

So for example, this line:

```
if (document.getElementById("display") === "Change my text!") {
```

should be:

```
if (document.getElementById("display").innerHTML === "Change my text!") {
```

Here's a working (and slightly shortened) version of your code:

```html
<!doctype.html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Javascript</h1>
  <p id="display">Change my text!</p>
  <button onClick="writeMe()">Click me!</button>
</body>
<script>
  function writeMe() {
    var el = document.getElementById("display");
    el.innerHTML === "Change my text!" ? el.innerHTML = "Hello world!" : el.innerHTML = "Change my text!";
  }
</script>

</html>
```